# PHP not storing session ID

Tags: php, mysql, oop, session, storage

I have been silently following along in here and now I joined myself.

I am in the making of a login system, purely for the learning of it, as i am semi-new to PHP (~2 months best guess).

Right now i get the following error (using WAMP and mysql):

> "Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$id in
>   C:\wamp64\www\login\classes\user.php on line 44"

This is the line WAMP is telling:

```
            session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
```

And here is the put(& get) function used:

```
public static function put($name, $value){
    return $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
}

public static function get($name){
    return $_SESSION[$name];}
```

My Login-system is working up until this login-point, even hash's and everything.

I am trying to store the ID of the user, so that when i want to check if it is functioning with the following:

```
echo session::get(config::get('session/session_name'));
```

after doing this in my user class:

```
$this->_sessionName = config::get('session/session_name');
```

It should just give me the number of the ID on the user (e.g. 2, if the user ID is 2(ID is auto incremented)). (the config holds basic arrays for DB-connection, session and token etc.)

But it is not.

I really hope this is not a duplicate question as i could not find a question that asked for this kind of use.

Is there anybody who can help me in the right direction?

Comment: What version of PHP is this?

Comment: Your error is on `$this->data()->id` where is that generated?

Comment: look below for my answer to @Mausumi

Answer (score 1):

well error is self explanatory

`$this->data()` in `user.php` returns stdClass without `id`

this is matter of simple debugging see what `$this->data()` returns...

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you to used a session class with static member function so that you can call that method from any where with its class name

and most importantly
use  [Error Control Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)  when u r going start a session.so that if session is going on, system won't start again and error will ignore so u can ensure about session variable

eg:-

```
<?php

class Session
{

    public static function init()
    {  
        @session_start(); //#
    }

    public static function set($key, $value)
    {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }

    public static function get($key)
    {

        if (isset($_SESSION[$key]))
            return $_SESSION[$key];
        else 
            return false;
    }

}
```

now use it like below:-

```
    <?php  
     require 'Session.php'; 
 class TestController{ 
    function setData()
    {
        Session::init(); 
        Session::set('user_id',1);//set userid to session
    }

    function getData()
    {
        Session::init(); //this also won't give you error;
        echo Session::get('user_id'); //get or retrieve userid from session
    } 
} 
?>
```

but use Session::init in constructor for good programming practice ..

Comment: I have a init.php file. i put at the top of the page like this: "require_once 'core/init.php';".

Right now it has my DB-connect array, my cookie array, and session array. 

the session array contains 'session_name' =>  'user'. and similar for the token, which works. 

correct me if i am wrong(which i very likely am), but isn't my put and get functions simpler versions of yours? 

Should the "->id" not be filled with the, well, ID this way?

Comment: i should add that my init.php also hold my session_start(), my spl_autoload_register for all my classes and my sanitizer.